# My Javascript does not seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble getting the Javascript to work. All three are in the same folder. Also Chrome takes a while to open, but Firefox is instant. Thanks.

My HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hover Over Me!</div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ABCDEF;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, .25);
});
```

Comment: You need an extra `});` at the end.

Comment: Use the developer console to spot such minor errors!

Comment: Using notepad++. Sorry I didn't copy it correct onto stackoverflow. I had the });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Order of script files: Since your script file is using jQuery it should be included after the jQuery library.

Please have a look at the browser console to see whether there is any error as the first step of debugging client side script issues

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hover Over Me!</div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Also you are missing closing brackets at the bottom of script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    });
    $('div').mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(1000, .25);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B0eDTFQ9Gsmzb10xT7Az?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know about order of scripts. Console log shows: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, and Failed to load resource .

Comment: @Nexus updated, you had included jQuery UI library instead of jQuery library

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined: script.js:1
Failed to load  resource:file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js

Comment: @Nexus did you check the demo

Comment: @Nexus try to update the src of jquery as `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.js`, it might be because you are running the test from a `file:xxx` address so you need to specify the protocol for the remote resource...

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Is the http necessary from here on out?